# Agrupar itens com diferença de data de 10 minutos entre sí

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tb_log`, nela tenho alguns dados `id`, `usuario_id`, `produto_id`,..., `data`.

Preciso agrupar os registros pela data da seguinte forma: Todos os registros que tiverem diferença de até 10 minutos entre si.

Ou seja, se o primeiro e o segundo tiver uma diferença de 10 minutos, agrupa, se o terceiro tiver diferença de 10 minutos com o primeiro ou o segundo, entra no mesmo agrupamento.

Comment: 1º Qual SGBD vc está usando?
2º O primeiro minuto começaria com 0?
3º O agrupamento por 10 minutos seria para posteriormente fazer se uma soma ou contagem dos registros?

Comment: Seria mais fácil um exemplo numérico , dados x saída requerida. Além de informar o tipo da coluna "data".

Answer (score -1):

Aqui estou considerando que teu campo `data` é `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT
    data, 
    usuario_id,
    count(usuario_id)
FROM tb_log 
WHERE …
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data) DIV 600, usuario_id
```